# Predict with sklearn-KNN using median (instead of mean)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

Sklearn-KNN allows one to set weights (e.g., uniform, distance) when calculating the *mean* x nearest neighbours.

Instead of predicting with the *mean*, is it possible to predict with the *median* (perhaps with a user-defined function)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no built-in parameter to adjust the weighting to use the median rather than the mean (you can see [in the source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/neighbors/regression.py#L153) that the mean is hard-coded). But because scikit-learn estimators are just Python classes, you can subclass `KNeighborsRegressor` and override the `predict` method to do whatever you want.

Here's a quick example, where I've copied and pasted the original `predict()` method and modified the relevant piece:

```
from sklearn.neighbors.regression import KNeighborsRegressor, check_array, _get_weights

class MedianKNNRegressor(KNeighborsRegressor):
    def predict(self, X):
        X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')

        neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)

        weights = _get_weights(neigh_dist, self.weights)

        _y = self._y
        if _y.ndim == 1:
            _y = _y.reshape((-1, 1))

        ######## Begin modification
        if weights is None:
            y_pred = np.median(_y[neigh_ind], axis=1)
        else:
            # y_pred = weighted_median(_y[neigh_ind], weights, axis=1)
            raise NotImplementedError("weighted median")
        ######### End modification

        if self._y.ndim == 1:
            y_pred = y_pred.ravel()

        return y_pred    

X = np.random.rand(100, 1)
y = 20 * X.ravel() + np.random.rand(100)
clf = MedianKNNRegressor().fit(X, y)
print(clf.predict(X[:5]))
# [  2.38172861  13.3871126    9.6737255    2.77561858  17.07392584]
```

I've left out the weighted version, because I don't know of a simple way to compute a weighted median with numpy/scipy, but it would be straightforward to add in once that function is available.

Comment: Just found the [wquantiles](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wquantiles) package which claims to implement the weighted median. I haven't checked it out, but you might find it useful!